# Tricky expression evaluation

Tags: c

I have this code:

```
  int main()
    {
       int a=1,b=2,c=3;
       printf("%d\n",a+=(a+=3,5,a));


       return 0;
    }
```

results in printing `8`. How is it possible?

In step 1, a=a+3 after taking out  `a+=3` makes it `a=4`

In step 2, `a+=(a+=3)` I made it to `a=a+(4)`and hence `a=4+4=8`. Moving this way I didn't succeed to make `a+=(a+=3,5,a)`equals to 8.

Comment: Can u be more specific please @JoachimPileborg

Comment: b and c are independant why do you put them there, you can deobfuscate this program less than it appears by removing unneeded variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comma operator is both a sequence point, and defines an order of evaluation (as in section 6.5.17 of the C specification). This operator evaluates the left operand, then evaluates the right operand and yields the value of the right-hand operand.

Let's break this down then:

```
(a+=3,5,a)
```

This will add 3 to a, then yield the value of the right hand, i.e.:

```
5, a
```

It will evaluate 5 as 5, then discard it. It will then evaluate `a`, then yield the value, `a` (i.e. 4). The rest then becomes:

```
a+=4
```

Which adds 4 to `a`, then yields the new value of `a`, which is 8.

NOTE: This is probably undefined behaviour, please see Vlad's answer below.

Comment: Wow...Thank u so much for explaining

Answer (score 2):

The program has undefined behaviour because. According to the C Standard (6.5.16 Assignment operators)

> 3. ...The side effect of updating the stored value of the left operand is sequenced after the value computations of the left and right
>      operands. The **evaluations of the operands are unsequenced**.

So in your example it might be that the left operand will be evaluated first and it will be equal tp 1.
In this case you will get result equal to 5.

In the right side of the compound assignment there is no any sense to include operands 5 and a in the comma operator. You could write simply

```
a += ( a += 3 );
```

instead of

```
a+=(a+=3,5,a));
```

Or you could make the code more funny. For example

```
a+=(a+=3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,b, c, a));
```

Comment: I realise now that this probably makes my answer invalid, but anyway. Doesn't using the comma operators create a sequence point in which the value of `a` will be updated?

Comment: @slugonamission  The sequence point excists only in the comma operator. However there is no sequence point in the assignment operator as it is written in the quote from the C Standard.

Comment: Wait, the version of the spec I read was slightly different (the side effect of updating the stored value is performed between the previous and next sequence points, or similar, I can't remember the exact phrasing).

Comment: @slugonamission N1548 Committee Draft — December 2, 2010 ISO/IEC 9899:201x